# Obsolete ABAP statement "COPY table TO table"?

Tags: abap

It seems, there once was an ABAP statement like `COPY table TO table.` that is so obsolete, it isn't mentioned in the ABAP keyword documentation anymore.  Anyone having information or examples?

We are writing a tool in Java that parses and transforms ABAP code. We therefore have no intention to write new ABAP code but our tool has to handle all of ABAP, even obsolete statements. Furthermore, I'm not an ABAP expert.

Comment: I can't remember any COPY statement from the past. ABAP is downward compatible (with some restrictions), so if a COPY statement has ever existed, it also has to be mentioned in the ABAP Help. If there is no single word about this statement, my assumption is, it never existed.

Comment: Do you have any mention somewhere about this unknown `COPY table TO table`, or is it just a myth or an urban legend?

Comment: Our tool works for various ABAP versions, some of which are no longer supported by SAP - customers still use those. So, that command might be no longer supported now but it might have been at some time.

Comment: I ask about that command because our tool accepts it - with a comment "what kind of command is that?". That code comment was added by a colleague that has long left the company. So, my guess is: at one point, out tool discovered such a statement, so it was added to the parser. But even at that time, it was not mentioned in the ABAP Keyword Documentation.

Comment: @UlrichScholz Is it possible that someone [defined a macro](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sap_abap/sap_abap_macros.htm) named `COPY` and your tool erroneously thought that this was a keyword?

Comment: @Philipp Currently, our tool has smooth support for macros. But as the issue is ages old, that might have been different back then, so a _developer_ might have thought that it was a keyword. I admit, that could be an explanation.
I will add some log output for that "statement". If it ever occurs, I will ping you.

Answer (score 4):

The ABAP language follows the design philosophy that old language constructs might be declared obsolete, or might be illegal in combination with new features. For example, when object-oriented programming was introduced, a lot of older statements became illegal if used within a method of a class.

But the ABAP language development group at SAP always followed the credo that a program which was *once* legal will *always* be legal.

Even keywords [which were obsolete for ages](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_750_index_htm/7.50/en-US/abenabap_obsolete.htm) can still be found in the documentation, just in case someone has to work with legacy code which still uses those language features. But there is no keyword `COPY` in [the alphabetic index](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_750_index_htm/7.50/en-US/abenabap_index.htm#C). There is only [the `<tt:copy>` node for XML transformations](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_750_index_htm/7.50/en-US/abenst_tt_copy.htm), but that does not seem to be what you are looking for.

So it seems to me that this keyword never existed.

Perhaps you are confusing it with [the obsolete `MOVE` keyword](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_750_index_htm/7.50/en-US/abapmove_obs.htm)?

```
MOVE table1 TO table2.
```

which is an archaic form of writing

```
table2 = table1.
```

Comment: Not completely sure about the following: "Even keywords which were obsolete for ages can still be found in the documentation". Although many obsolete language parts are mentioned, it might not be 100% of all accepted obsolete constructs.  For example, we just had a case of lines beginning with `<R2>` (if I remember correctly). I wonder how old they might be. By now, I have not found that in the ABAP Keyword Documentation.

Comment: @UlrichScholz Maybe you mean the `#r2` and `#r3` preprocessor directives? These ones indeed appears to be undocumented. But they are in fact still valid code which can be activated and executed. COPY is not. Which makes me believe that this instruction never existed, documented or not.

Comment: @UlrichScholz But if you can show me an ABAP code snippet which uses that `COPY a TO b` construct and which can still be activated, then that would convince me that I am wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your tables are same types and the first one is not empty
You can do:
itab2[] = itab1[]

or, if you have to append rows:
append lines itab1 to itab2

If the table are different you can do:
Loop at itab1 into wa1.
move-corresponding wa1 to wa2.
append wa2 to itab2.
clear wa2.
endloop.

or:
Loop at itab1 into wa1.
wa2-field1 = wa1-field2
...
and so on
...
append wa2 to itab2.
clear wa2.
endloop.

or you can use a field-symbols:
field-symbol:  like line of itab1.

Loop at itab1 assigning  (if the system is 730, you can declare field symbol in line with assigning field-symbols())
wa2-field1 = -field2
...
and so on
...
append wa2 to itab2.
clear wa2.
endloop.